# BroadcastReceiver with ResultReceiver and lifetime

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have interrogation about the way to use a BroadcastReceiver with a ResultReceiver in it.

I know that if "A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds.", there is an ANR.

I have an application that respond to an Intent, declared in the Manifest.
It is a BroadcastReceiver that start a service because it needs to make some networks operations:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context context = null;
    private MyResultReceiver myResultReceiver = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        this.context = context;
        myResultReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(context, MyService.class);
        i.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_RESULT_RECEIVER, myResultReceiver);
        context.startService(i);
    }

    public class MyResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

        public MyResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            if (resultCode == 42) {
                // Something
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My service looks like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private Context context = null;
    private ResultReceiver resultReceiver = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        this.context = this;
        resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.EXTRA_RESULT_RECEIVER);
        MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
        myTask.execute();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Network operation
            return status;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean status) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            if (status == true) {
                if (resultReceiver != null) {
                    resultReceiver.send(42, null);
                }
            } else {
                if (resultReceiver != null) {
                    resultReceiver.send(-1, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, am I sure that the resultReceiver still exist and will do what it have to do if the network operation is longer than 10 seconds ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [relevant documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) from the SDK:

> If this BroadcastReceiver was launched through a  tag, then
>   the object is no longer alive after returning from this function. This
>   means you should not perform any operations that return a result to
>   you asynchronously -- in particular, for interacting with services,
>   you should use startService(Intent) instead of bindService(Intent,
>   ServiceConnection, int). If you wish to interact with a service that
>   is already running, you can use peekService(Context, Intent).
>
> The Intent filters used in registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver,
>   IntentFilter) and in application manifests are not guaranteed to be
>   exclusive. They are hints to the operating system about how to find
>   suitable recipients. It is possible for senders to force delivery to
>   specific recipients, bypassing filter resolution. For this reason,
>   onReceive() implementations should respond only to known actions,
>   ignoring any unexpected Intents that they may receive.

Bottom line:

1. If you start a service, use `startService(Intent)`.
2. Don't do long running applications on `onReceive`.
3. AsyncTasks may be destroyed, your best bet is to use a Service. If you are using an AsyncTask inside of a Service, it should be fine.

Comment: WRT your "bottom line" - 1. The OP *IS* using `startService(...)`. 2. The OP knows this, hence the question. 3. The OP *IS* using a `Service`. Admittedly using an `AsyncTask` inside a `Service` is pointless (bearing in mind an `AsyncTask` is designed to interact with a UI) but even so an `AsyncTask` is a lot less likely to be destroyed in a `Service` than in an `Activity`.

Comment: As @Squonk said, this answer doesn't help me. But thanks for trying.